# Have to use sleep with pyserial when opening com port for arduino nano

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm running pyserial (3.1.1) on Windows 10 with python 2.7

Update - get the same issue running on Xubuntu 16 as well as Windows.

I'm writing via serial to an arduino nano via usb / serial interface.

I'm writing a simple character string (eg. '2+') and reading the output in the arduino. If I keep the first time.sleep at 2 seconds after opening the com port it works. If I change it to 1 or remove it the arduino seems to receive a different character / encoding and it does not work.

Ideally I don't want any sleep so that it works quicker. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this so that I can remove the sleep or at least reduce it?

Python Code:

```
import sys, getopt
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
time.sleep(1)  #change this to 2 and it works
ser.write('2+')
out = ''
time.sleep(1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.read(1)
if out != '':
    print ">>" + out
else:
    print ">> nothing!"
time.sleep(1)   
ser.close()
```

Arduino code (I'm having some minor issues with the ASCII char numbers as well - I think it is the signing of the bytes but that is the least of my problems at the moment)

```
String inString = ""; 
int pinNumber = 0;

void setup() {
    // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // expected input:    1+   //to change the digital pin to on
    // expected input:    2-   //to change the digital pin to off  
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        //char inChar = char(int(Serial.read()));
        char inChar = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(inChar);
        if (isDigit(inChar)) {
            inString += inChar;
            Serial.println(inString);
        }
        else {
            pinNumber = inString.toInt();
            Serial.println(pinNumber);
            pinMode(pinNumber, OUTPUT);
        if (inChar == -85) {
            Serial.println("set high");
            digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);  
        } else if (inChar == -83) {
            Serial.println("set low");
            digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW);  
        } else {
            Serial.println("NO MATCH!!!");
        }
        inString = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried putting a `ser.flush()` in your python code right after the `ser.write('2+')` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the ser.flush() and it doesn't change anything - I still need the sleep for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that if there is data, it will be the full data. If there is buffering in how the serial port is handled on the transmitting part, you will get only partial data.

You can try and add a `ser.flush()` in your python code, but you should also check that the data you received is complete. You can do that by making sure that your data terminates with a known character and checking that.

Keep in mind that you should also have a timeout of some sort, so that you don't get stuck in some reading loop.

Another problem is that you're reading a `char` type, but `Serial.read()` actually return an `int`, according to [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read). The `char` data type has a size of 1 byte, while `int` has a size of 2 bytes, so that's probably why you're getting weird stuff (there's a reference [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DatatypePractices)).

It also says that `read` will return only the first byte of the data. So, if you want the second byte, you need to read twice.

Comment: Thanks - serial didn't work but appreciate the help with the serial.read() on the arduino and the differentiation between char / int

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your Arduino is reset automatically when opening a serial connection?

In the Arduino Nano, the RESET pin is connected to DTR of the FTDI USB to serial converter via C4. See [Arduino Nano Schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf).

Maybe if you remove C4 or disable DTR your problem will disappear.

You can check this by putting a short LED pulse in the setup function and see if it happens after opening the serial port from your Python program.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any way around this sleep issue. The bytes were only received correctly on the arduino if at least 1.5 seconds was allowed - presumably for the serial connection to initialise.

As a workaround I had to open the serial port once on startup and then accept and write data through a socket server. This worked as expected. It seems the issue is with the opening of the serial port.

```
import os, os.path
import time
import serial
import socket
import re

def sendData(msg):
    if not ser.is_open:
        ser.open()
    ser.write(msg)
    ser.flush()
    out = ''
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        out += ser.read(1)
    if out != '':
        print ">>" + out
    else:
        print ">> nothing!"
    time.sleep(0.5) 

port='/dev/ttyUSB1',

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 9000))
serversocket.listen(1) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

ser = serial.Serial(
    port=port,
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print buf
        sendData(buf)
```